# Probability of Detection

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There exist radars used for detecting aircrafts passing through the state of Iowa.  The state only has three radars, with each having a 25% chance of failing to detect a plane in the state.  Suddenly, a plane has entered the state.
>
> What is the probability the plane is detected?
>
> Let’s say the plane was detected.  What is the probability that at least two of the radars detected the plane?

For the first question I computed $(1-.25)^3$ since there are three aircrafts and it would be a $75%$ percent chance the planes are detected.

For the second part I am less sure but would it be $(.25)(.75)^2$ since there are two radars that detect and one that doesn’t?

Comment: Part A:  I think you mean $P_D = 1 - (.25)^3$ since to not be detected all three radars must not detect.  Assuming the radars operate independently.

Comment: What does it mean "two of the radars detected the plane"?  Exactly two (and not three)?

Comment: @mjw I meant at least not exactly 2, my mistake I fixed it..

Comment: okay, thanks! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: made the change based on your update.  The calculation is similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part A: plane is not detected by all three radars with probability 
$$
\mathbb P(A^c)=0.25^3
$$
The probability that plane is detected (by at least one radar) is
$$
\mathbb P(A)=1-0.25^3.
$$

Part B: you have to find conditional probability that two radard detect plane (event $B$) if it is given that the plane is detected. It is
$$
\mathbb P(B\mid A) = \frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(A)}=\frac{\mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A)} =\frac{\binom{3}{2}\cdot(1-0.25)^2\cdot 0.25}{1-0.25^3}=\frac{3\cdot(1-0.25)^2\cdot 0.25}{1-0.25^3}.
$$
Here $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(B)$ since $B\subset A$.

**Edit after the question is corrected**

If $C$ is an event that at least two radars detect plane, then 
$$
\mathbb P(C) = 3\cdot(1-0.25)^2\cdot 0.25 + (1-0.25)^3 
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb P(C\mid A) = \frac{\mathbb P(A\cap C)}{\mathbb P(A)}=\frac{\mathbb P(C)}{\mathbb P(A)}. 
$$

Comment: My question was poorly worded and I fixed it for part b), is the explanation for part b for at least 2 cause that is what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Part A:  $P_D =1-(.25)^3.$

Part B:

$$P(\textrm{Exactly two detected})=3(.25)(.75)^2,$$
$$P(\textrm{Exactly three detected})=(.75)^3$$

so

$$P(\textrm{At least two detected}) = 3(.25)(.75)^2 + (.75)^3$$

and $$P(\textrm{Detected}|\textrm{At least two detected})=1,$$

we have

$$P(\textrm{At least two detected}|\textrm{Detected})=\frac{P(\textrm{Detected}|\textrm{At least two detected}) P(\textrm{At least two detected})}{P(\textrm{Detected})}$$

$$=\frac{ 3(.25)(.75)^2 +(.75)^3}{1-(.25)^3}.$$

Comment: These are given as probabilities, not "odds" which is related, but not exactly the same.

Comment: The probability that must be found is conditional. The condition is that "at least one detected the plane".

Comment: Thank you @drhap!  Made the correction.

Comment: My question was poorly worded and I fixed it for part b), is the explanation for part b for at least 2 cause that is what I meant

Comment: Updated.  Similar calculation.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question you calculated the probability that all $3$ radars detected the plane.

The correct answer is: $$1-0.25^3$$i.e. $1$ minus the probability that none of the $3$ radars detected the plane.

---

The second question is ambiguous.

If in the second question the words "two of the radars" is to be read as "exactly two of the radars" then you should find: $$P(R=2\mid R\neq0)$$ where $R$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=3$ and $p=0.75$.

(Here $R$ stands for the number of radars that detected the plane)

If however the words must be read as "at least two of the radars" then you must go for finding: $$P(R\geq2\mid R\neq0)$$

The probabilities can be calculated by applying the general rule: $$P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$$

Can you do that yourself?